# Maven 'forget' classes it generated in previous 'package' command

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I quite stuck with something I think is basic, but Maven does not enable me to package my project twice without doing some cleaning.

I'm working on a java project with multi-dependencies (different modules developped by different people, usual stuff) and one of them uses java classes generated using JAXB.
I'm using maven to make all that work together (one pom per module and one pom parent to built the whole project, basic stuff I said).

When I package the modules using dedicated pom there is no trouble (even if I do several successive package without cleaning). When I package the whole project for the first time (or after a clean) there is no problem at all too (*.java generated from XSDs, *.class, tests executed, Jar generated properly).

But now, if I re-do the package command, then maven says that it cannot find the classes generated using JAXB (and, then there are compilation issues in other java classes due to symbols that cannot be found, logic).

I think that Maven kind of "forgot" that it generated java classes during previous package but I don't know how to make it remember. So, up to now, I'm obliged to make it generate those classes and delete them, again and again (and its quite long as the clean cleans every other modules that will then be built again...).

So, if anyone has any clue on what I'm missing/doing wrong, I would be glad as none of my search here and there were successful.

I hope that I was clear enough. If not, feel free to ask for further explanation.

Thank you

P.S. I forgot to tell you that I'm using Maven with command line

EDIT :

Parent POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.package.for.mysoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysoft-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Main parent for MySoft modules</name>

<properties>
  <mysoft_version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</mysoft_version>
  <main_other_soft_version>1.3.1</main_other_soft_version>

  <!-- SCADAsoft packages -->
  <scadasoft.version>6.2.4.4</scadasoft.version>

  <!-- Hypervisor packages -->
  <othersoft2.version>2.9.0_P03</othersoft2.version>
  <othersoft1.version>1.8.0_P03</othersoft1.version>
  <othersoft3.version>1.2.8</othersoft3.version>
  <hv.quartz-tc.version>2.2.1</hv.quartz-tc.version>

  <!-- TVS packages -->
  <tvs.common.version>3.6.5.0001</tvs.common.version>

  <!-- Loggers -->
  <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
  <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

    <modules>
    <module>mysoft-bom</module>
    <module>mysoft-jaxb</module>
    <module>mysoft-common</module>
    <module>My-project-that-uses-jaxb-generated-classes</module>
    </modules>

  <distributionManagement>  
    <snapshotRepository>  
      <id>soft-repo-releases</id>  
      <name>SOFT maven repository - SNAPSHOTS</name>  
      <url>http://url.of.the.server:123/nexus/content/repositories/mysoft_snapshots/</url>  
    </snapshotRepository>  
    <repository>  
      <id>soft-repo-releases</id>  
      <name>Soft maven repository - RELEASES</name>  
      <url>http://url.of.the.server:123/nexus/content/repositories/mysoft_releases/</url>  
    </repository>  
  </distributionManagement>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.terracotta.quartz</groupId>
      <artifactId>quartz-terracotta</artifactId>
      <version>${hv.quartz-tc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <deployAtEnd>false</deployAtEnd>
        <skip>false</skip>
      </configuration>

    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>enforce-parent-version</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>enforce</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <rules>
              <requireProperty>
                <property>project.parent.version</property>
                <regex>1.3.0.SNAPSHOT</regex>
              </requireProperty>
            </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>

</project>
```

Pom of the module that generates java classes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>mysoft-jaxb</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>my.package.for.mysoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysoft-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <name>MySoft generated classes</name>
  <description>Classes generated by JAXB</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <othersoft1.version>1.8.0</othersoft1.version>
    <othersoft2.version>2.9.0</othersoft2.version>
    <othersoft3.version>1.2.8</othersoft3.version>
    <mysoft.data.model>${main_other_soft_version}</mysoft.data.model>
    <mysoft.common>${main_other_soft_version}</mysoft.common>
    <mysoft.core>${main_other_soft_version}</mysoft.core>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </properties>

  <distributionManagement>  
    <snapshotRepository>  
      <id>soft-repo-releases</id>  
      <name>Soft maven repository - SNAPSHOTS</name>  
      <url>http://url.of.the.server:123/nexus/content/repositories/mysoft_snapshots/</url>  
    </snapshotRepository>  
    <repository>  
      <id>soft-repo-releases</id>  
      <name>Soft maven repository - RELEASES</name>  
      <url>http://url.of.the.server:123/nexus/content/repositories/mysoft_releases/</url>  
    </repository>  
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.5</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <environmentVariables>
              <PATH>${java.library.path};${my_api_dir}\Bin;${project.basedir}\..\module-with-cpp\target\nar\lib\x86-Windows-msvc\jni</PATH>
            </environmentVariables>

            <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Compiler plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven Jar plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven Check Style Plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin Plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven JavaDoc Plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <!-- generation of java classes using JAXB -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../resources/xsd/config.xsd</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>system_configuration/**</exclude>
            <exclude>mysoft.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>connector_configuration.xml</exclude>
            <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Module that uses the one with JAXB generated java classes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>My-project-that-uses-jaxb-generated-classes</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>my.package.for.mysoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysoft-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <name>My project module 1</name>
  <description>Module that uses Jaxb generated classes</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <othersoft1.version>1.8.0</othersoft1.version>
    <othersoft2.version>2.9.0</othersoft2.version>
    <othersoft3.version>1.2.8</othersoft3.version>
    <mysoft.data.model>${main_other_soft_version}</mysoft.data.model>
    <mysoft.common>${main_other_soft_version}</mysoft.common>
    <mysoft.core>${main_other_soft_version}</mysoft.core>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </properties>

  <distributionManagement>  
    <snapshotRepository>  
      <id>soft-repo-releases</id>  
      <name>Soft maven repository - SNAPSHOTS</name>  
      <url>http://url.of.the.server:123/nexus/content/repositories/mysoft_snapshots/</url>  
    </snapshotRepository>  
    <repository>  
      <id>soft-repo-releases</id>  
      <name>Soft maven repository - RELEASES</name>  
      <url>http://url.of.the.server:123/nexus/content/repositories/mysoft_releases/</url>  
    </repository>  
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>dependency.package.1</groupId>
      <artifactId>connector-sdk-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- datamodels -->     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dependency.package.1</groupId>
      <artifactId>data-model-1</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.5.0001</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>dependency.package.2</groupId>
      <artifactId>data-model-2</artifactId>
      <version>${scadasoft.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 

    ...

    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.package.for.mysoft</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysoft-common</artifactId>
      <version>${mysoft_version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.package.for.mysoft</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysoft-jaxb</artifactId>
      <version>${mysoft_version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <environmentVariables>
              <PATH>${java.library.path};${my_api_dir}\Bin;${project.basedir}\..\module-with-cpp\target\nar\lib\x86-Windows-msvc\jni</PATH>
            </environmentVariables>
            <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Compiler plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven Jar plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven Check Style Plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin Plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
        <!-- Maven JavaDoc Plugin: Inherited from Parent -->
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>system_configuration/**</exclude>
            <exclude>mysoft.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>connector_configuration.xml</exclude>
            <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- One of the dependencies uses C++ -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
        <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>nar-download</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>nar-download</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>nar-test-unpack</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>nar-test-unpack</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>nar-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>nar-integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This can't be answered without actually seeing your poms. This is probably very specific to the code-generating plugins you are using.

Comment: Thank you @bmargulies. I edited my question with some of the poms I'm using. I hope it may help.